# Lightweight Audio Waveform Viewer

Tags: audio, quicklook-plugin, waveform

I'm doing a large amount of music library updating and de-duplicating and evaluating, and I would like a piece of software that would allow me to quickly be able to view a waveform of a selected audio file.

I currently use Fission for editing, but it loads slower than I would like, and I have no need for the actual editing aspect of the software. Additionally, Garageband is antagonistically slow and too hard to examine the waveform like I would like.

Is there software, or maybe something like a QuickLook plugin, that would allow me to select an audio file, and quickly get a rendered version of the waveform data within the file?

Loudness levels labels are appreciated, but not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a Quick Look plugin, but [Sound Studio](http://felttip.com/ss/) it is fairly lightweight, and displays the waveform:

[image]

However, I'm afraid I don't think you'll find the waveform itself to be particularly useful for determining duplicate songs.

Answer (score 2):

Try Audacity.  It doesn't seem to heavyweight for just waveform viewing.

Comment: Audacity is free. I don't find it all that well-designed or useful, but if all you want to do is view waveforms, why not give it a try? http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

I have tried two options:

[image]

https://github.com/seagirl/QLWaveForm/releases/tag/v1.0 << that worked

https://github.com/ideoforms/qlspectrogram << Doesn't work on catalina

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Snapper 2 from Audio Ease:

http://www.audioease.com/Pages/Snapper/SnapperMain.html#

I was looking for the same thing but this is the only all-in-one, finder level waveform viewer I could find.

Comment: Anything newer & better?

Answer (score 1):

The 'lightest' app I've found to see a waveform is Nulloy

http://nulloy.com/

But I wish there were a Quick Look plugin.

Comment: Good, but been buggy for me for years.